# mysql select error for uppercase and lowercase table names

Tags: mysql

I have a table let say is it called "test".
I use Ubuntu and MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6 version.
If I try to do "select * from test" it works but if try "select * from Test" or "select * from TEST" it does not work.
Does any had this problem, or knows how to solve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your system (Unix, Windows and Mac OS for the main values).

You need to set your system variable "lower_case_table_names" to 1 or 2, to make your database case insensitive.

```
SET lower_case_table_names=1;
```

or

```
SET lower_case_table_names=2;
```

More at [Mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Table names case sensitivity depends on the operating system,.

on windows table names are case insensitive while on *nix systems table names are case-sensitive,.

its always a good practice to use lower-case for table names, when creating the table and when accessing the table through a query., this way you would never face any case-sensitivity problems.,